# Alpha-Numeric Value Format

Tags: custom-field-types, default-value

How can I set up a required value format in a custom form text field?
example:

Q###-######

Q310-12345

Answer (score 1):

Sunny,

You can create a custom field type for your requirement as shown in the [Walkthrough on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861799%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

It is kind of same you are looking for, it validates the input as ISBN number.. You can customize it to fit your needs..

If you don't want to use custom field type than I suggest to convert your list forms on InfoPath forms and in InfoPath you can use Rules to make sure the input is required pattern. The [video shows how to validate a textbox input for particular pattern](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8hqkoN6_MI)

PS: InfoPath forms are only available in Enterprise version of SharePoint